# Loop through each subdirectory without going deeper -- Batch script

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory, subdirectory

I've been looking for a while to see if I can make a script that goes into a subdirectory but stops, executes a command, then leaves the directory without going into any of the sub-sub directories. Here's what I've got so far:

```
FOR /R "%cd%" %%G in (.) DO (
    cd %%G
    echo %%G
    cd ..
)
```

but the problem is that it just keeps going through each subdirectory without stopping, so it looks like this:

```
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\models\.
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\models\weapons\.
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\sound\.
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\sound\impacts\.
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\sound\weapons\.
now in C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\(gdcw)_usp_.45_silenced_300572504\sound\weapons\usp45\.
```

instead of just going into the first subdirectory from the folder "Batch GMA Converter". Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You need to show us what `%CD%` is to get the output you posted; I think you could replace the `for /R` loop by nested `for /D` loops...

Comment: If you used common sense, you can tell %cd% is C:\Users\JacobGunther12\Desktop\Batch GMA Converter\ @aschipfl

Comment: What is common sense, @JacobGunther? ...no, seriously, I prefer to ask the OP, because you never know how they understand the term "subdirectory" (sub to what root?); every information not stated in a question could be assumed wrongly and so lead to false conclusions...

Comment: If you look in my code at like 1, it says %cd% and then look at my output code, it literately shows the directory. As you can use common sense to figure out that the Batch GMA Converter directory is the top directory since I said "subdirectories", meaning multiple directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through a *static list* of subdirectories obtained from `dir /B /AD` as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "curdir=%CD%"
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /AD') DO (
    pushd "%curdir%\%%G"
    echo %curdir%\%%G
    popd
)
```